# Can't insert data with Firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

After I heard about Firebase, I decided it was a good idea to try it on my little Unity game.

I readed the documentation, followed the "Get Started" configuration tutorials, and changed the authentication rules so everyone could insert data.

```
void Start()
{
    // Set up the Editor before calling into the realtime database.
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://magicast-bd2fc.firebaseio.com/");

    Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.StateChanged += DefaultInstance_StateChanged;

    // Get the root reference location of the database.
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;

    var u = new User();
    u.email = "sdjkdsdksadjsad";
    u.fb_id = "sakdsajdhasd";
    u.username = "jadhsjahjsda";
    reference.SetValueAsync(u);
}
```

This code does execute, but when I go to my Firebase Console, I see no data on the Database tab. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, and the code gives no errors at all! What am I doing wrong?

This is my user class. It's basically a testing class, no big stuff:

```
public class User
    {
        public string username;
        public string email;
        public string fb_id;

        public User()
        {
        }

        public User(string username, string email, string fb_id)
        {
            this.username = username;
            this.email = email;
            this.fb_id = fb_id;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `.set()` on arbitrary objects to the Firebase Database, they must come under one of the following categories:

- `string`
- `long`
- `double`
- `bool`
- `Dictionary<string, Object>`
- `List<Object>`

Instead of

```
reference.SetValueAsync(u);
```

You need to call

```
string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(u);
reference.SetRawJsonValueAsync(json);
```

You are also not actually logging in any user. To log in an anonymous user, first go to the Firebase Console -> Authentication and turn on the 'Anonymous' switch. Then authenticate with the following code:

```
Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;

auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
  if (task.IsCanceled) {
    Debug.LogError("SignInAnonymouslyAsync was canceled.");
    return;
  }
  if (task.IsFaulted) {
    Debug.LogError("SignInAnonymouslyAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
    return;
  }

  Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
  Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
      newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not authenticated and the default Firebase security rules require that `auth != null`.

See the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/start) for how to authenticate with Unity.

Comment: As I said on the question, I changed the authentication rules so everyone could insert data. My rules currently are:   "read" : "true", "write" : "true"

Comment: @ArturoTemplário In that case it's probably that `User` object. You can call `.set()` on a simple value or a json dictionary-type structure, not on arbitrary objects.

Comment: Previously I used the JsonUtility class to serialize the User object, as they do in the example docs. Shouldn't it have worked?

Comment: you need to call `string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(u);` and then `reference.SetRawJsonValueAsync(json);` - from the docs.

Comment: I did exactly that json converting, but it still did not worked. Ok, I'll be waiting, and thanks in advance

Comment: Sure, wait a sec

Comment: Check my new answer for how to log in and serialise the object. It should work...